# Drawing interactively from the bash history to construct a complete command?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

At the bash prompt the command history can be explored using the up and down arrow keys. (I also often use CTRL+R.) Is it possible to do this without replacing the character string to the left of the cursor.

For example, I may have found two files using ls:

```
$ ls ../../blah/foo/bar/CMakeLists.txt

$ ls /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h
```

I'd now like to shunt the second path into the first file. I begin by pressing the up arrow; then CTRL+A; and removing ls from the start using delete:

```
$ /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h
```

I'd now like to use >> to append this path to the CMakeLists.txt file; which I will later edit from within a text editor. The command I'd like to create is:

```
$ echo /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h >> ../../blah/foo/bar/CMakeLists.txt
```

It would be nice if I could scroll interactively through the history to locate the CMakeLists.txt path while leaving the .../c++config.h part untouched.

One possibility would be to use !! and !-N event designators, but if possible I'd much prefer something interactive; such as the up and down arrows; or CTRL+R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll use the key nomenclature used in the Readline documentation, namely that the Control key is represented by a `C`, so `C-k` is `CTRL-K`)

Find the first one with `C-r`, then `C-d` or Del 3 times to delete the `ls`. Then `C-k` to kill (cut) the rest of the line. Then `C-r` to search for the other one. `C-e` to move to the end of the line. Type `>>`. Then `C-y` to yank (paste) in the first path.

So, `C-k` (kill) and `C-y` (yank) are probably your best tools for this job.

Comment: This is great: I didn't know about yank and kill.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with vi, you can set bash to vi mode with `set -o vi` and then use regular vi commands.

For example in your case `f.y$` to yank the path in the first command line, then go the the next line with `j`, type `$p` to append the previously yanked text at the end of the line and finally clean-up the line with `0cwecho<esc>f a>><esc>`